# Randomness of rightmost bits from LCGs

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, random

**Task:** Show that the sequence of integers made up of the $k$ rightmost bits generated by an LCG with $m = 2^n$ has a period of at most $2^k$.

I actually get a hint to define the output as the following: $R_i = X_i \operatorname{mod} 2^k$ and derive a recursion.

The LCG algorithm is to provide a seed $X_0$ and iterate for $i \geq 1$,
$$
X_i = aX_{i-1} + c \operatorname{mod} 2^n; \ \ R_i = X_i \operatorname{mod} 2^k.
$$
Deriving a recursion for $R_i$ is difficult when $c \neq 0$, so I thought to set $c = 0$. Then,
$$
R_i = a^jx_0 \operatorname{mod} 2^k.
$$
How can I derive from this that the period is at most $2^k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, for all nonnegative integer $x$ and positive integer $m$, the notation "$x\bmod m$" means the (unique) least nonpositive integer the difference between which and $x$ is a multiple of $m$. Or `x % m` in programming languages.

Verify that
$$ X_i = aX_{i-1} + c \bmod 2^n $$
implies
$$ R_i = aR_{i-1} + c \bmod 2^k $$
In particular, **$R_{i}$ is uniquely determined by $R_{i-1}$.**

Consider $R_0, R_1, \cdots, R_{2^k}$, which are $2^k+1$ integers between $0$ and $2^k-1$. Thanks to Pigeonhole principle, two of them must be the same. Suppose they are $R_i$ and $R_j$, where $0\le i<j\le 2^k$.

- $R_i=R_j$ implies $R_{i+1}=R_{j+1}$.
- $R_{i+1}=R_{j+1}$ implies $R_{i+2}=R_{j+2}$.
- $R_{i+2}=R_{j+2}$ implies $R_{i+3}=R_{j+3}$.
- $\vdots$.

So the sequence $R_0, R_1, \cdots$ has a period of $j-i$, which is at most $2^k$.

Comment: I should have included the conditions "$R_{i-1} = X_{i-1} \bmod 2^k$" and "$R_i = X_i \bmod 2^k$" . $\ k\le n$ is assumed; otherwise $R_i=X_i$ is the same as in the case of $k=n$, which has been proved.